# Speed of blast from supernova

Tags: supernova, explosion

How fast does the blast front of a supernova expand at? Is it close to the speed of light or is it less than a quarter of the speed of light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The speed of the blast front depends on the initial energy release and the density of the medium into which it is expanding, see [here](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~ryden/ast825/ch5-6.pdf).

Theory suggests and [measurements confirm expansion](http://jila.colorado.edu/~dick/Racusin09.pdf) rates of the order of thousands of km/s or a few $\times 10^6\ \mbox{m/s}$ or  $\sim 1\% \mbox{c}$.

Comment: The initial velocity of the blast wave is quite a bit larger, more like 10,000 to 30,000 km/s, i.e. ~10% of the speed of light. Still less than a quarter of the speed of light, though.

Comment: Crab nebula, remnant of SN 1054, is still expanding at  1,000 kilometers per second: http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap130905.html